# Admin ajax error 400 when passing select value to populate another select

Tags: ajax, select

This is my first attempt to write a plugin and I get an error 400 when trying to use admin-ajax.php. I've looked through some topics both here and in the WordPress support forum, but cannot figure it out.

What I am trying to do is dependant drop-down select. I.e. you chose an option from select #1, then it has to be passed via ajax to populate the second dropdown. To make it simple (for now), everything is on my "frontend" file.

Here is my code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <select class="cat-select" name="lvl1" id="lvl1">
                <option value="">-- select category --</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($this->getTopLevelCategories() as $category) {
                    print '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '">' . $category->name . ' (' . $category->count . ')</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('#lvl1').change(function () {
                    var lvl1Val = jQuery('#lvl1').val();
                    jQuery('#lvl2').empty();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            'action':'getLVl2',
                            'lvl1' : document.getElementById('lvl1').value
                        },
                        success: function(response, status) {
                            jQuery('#lvl2').append(response);
                            alert(response);
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(errorThrown){
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <select class="cat-select" name="lvl2" id="lvl2">
                <option value="" disabled selected>-- select category lvl2 --</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <?php

        function getLVl2()
        {
            if (isset($_POST['lvl1'])) :

                $parent = $_POST['lvl1'];

                $option = '<option value="' . $parent . '">';
                $option .= $parent;
                $option .= '</option>';

                echo $option;

                wp_die();

            endif;
        }

        add_action('wp_ajax_getLVl2', 'getLVl2');
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getLVl2', 'getLVl2');
        ?>
```

Note:

1. The code in the function will be changed. What I am trying to do is output the value of the option selected from the first dropdown just to see that it works.
2. The function and the script will be moved to their places to "keep the code clean"

Comment: A 400 error indicates that your AJAX actions are not being registered or registered late, so generally in a theme, you should register them via the `functions.php` file. Did you put your `getLVl2()` function and `add_action()` code in the functions file? Also, have you considered using the REST API instead (which can give you a pretty route/path like `my-plugin/v1/getLVl2`)?

Comment: No, I don't have them on the template functions.php. I have them in my plugin only.

As for the REST API - I've mentioned this is my first attempt to write WordPress plugin so I think it will be more complicated for me than "the usual" way.

Comment: As for the REST API, you would want to read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), but there are actually built-in endpoints for fetching terms in a specific *taxonomy*, e.g. [`/wp/v2/categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/) for the core `category` taxonomy. So for example, `fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories' )` would let you, via JS, fetch the site's categories.

Comment: As for your plugin, where are you calling the `add_action()`? Is it at the root in the plugin file, e.g. `<?php /* Plugin Name: My Plugin */ ... add_action( ... );` ?

Comment: I've moved the `add_action()` to the main plugin file and now they are registered. The ajax call goes through, but I have another problem - it returns 0. So I;m playing with where I should put my `function getLVl2() { ... }`

Comment: If you are getting a 0, then that likely means the `$_POST['lvl1']` was not set - and you just need to ensure that your JS sends the proper data. So you could just do `var_dump( $_POST );` before the `if` block and you'd know for sure if my guess was correct.

Comment: I've made it simpler: `function getLVl2(){ echo "Ajax Response"; wp_die(); }`
First tried to put it in the main plugin file, after the `add_action(...)` - returns 0.
Then tried in the file that renders the select fields (Select fields -> <script></script> -> function {}) - and again returns 0. As I have `wp_die()` at the end, the only option is that WordPress cannot find the function. Also, if I try in browser `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getLVl2` it also displays 0.

Comment: In that case, are you sure about this: "*now they are registered. The ajax call goes through*"? And I've posted an answer with a very simple plugin, so try that and see if it works for you? (after clearing all your caches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This may not definitively answer the question, but I hope this helps you in finding the most appropriate solution.* And actually, I've tried the super simple plugin at the bottom with your HTML and JS, and everything worked fine for me.

> This is my first attempt to write a plugin and I get an error 400 when trying to use admin-ajax.php

These are the common reasons why would `admin-ajax.php` return a 400 error (or a HTTP status of "400 Bad Request") and then display a `0`:

1. Your AJAX action was never registered or it's registered late.
2. Your JS script or AJAX request did not include the correct [`action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#action) value, i.e. the part after [`wp_ajax_`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/).
3. The current user is not logged-in and your AJAX action was registered only for logged-in users.

   Or the other way round — the user is logged-in, but your AJAX action was only for non logged-in users.

And in your case, where the AJAX action is `getLVl2`, the 400 error was likely due to reason #1 above, because your JS is sending the correct action and it's also registered for both logged-in and non logged-in users, i.e. you hooked on both `wp_ajax_getLVl2` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_getLVl2`.

So you'd just need to ensure you are calling `add_action()` at the right time, e.g. in the main plugin file like so (which should be located at `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`):

```php
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 */

function getLVl2() {
//  echo 'test';
    echo '<option>test</option>';
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getLVl2', 'getLVl2' );        // for logged-in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getLVl2', 'getLVl2' ); // for non logged-in users
```

Now try, using your browser, visiting `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getLVl2` and check if the `test` is displayed on the page.

Comment: Through some testing, I've already found out that the `add_action` and the functions called from the ajax should be in the main plugin file. Everything works now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :) And actually, they don't necessarily need to be in the main plugin file, so for example you can put them in external PHP file and load it via the main plugin file, e.g. `require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/your-file.php';`. What's important for you to remember is that the `add_action()` should be called before or by the time WordPress runs the `admin_init` hook.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP in an admin-side app. My code is virtually the same both in the callback and the function, with the exception of `ajaxurl` for the `url:`. I've tried `add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_function` in both the calling .php and the called .php. So, my runtime error is `https://foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)` and a response of `0`. If I try it in the browser: `https://foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=some_function`, I get a `0`. What else can I do to test?

Comment: @breadwild I just wanted to say sorry for the late reply, and be sure to use the correct hook when registering your AJAX actions or calling `add_action()`  (I've seen your question about the issue)