# Ajax call to a function in another module returns a 400 (Bad Request) error

Tags: ajax

Caveat: this very close to [Admin ajax error 400 when passing select value to populate another select](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/406924/) (and others) but know seeing an answer that applies. I've looked at several good blogs and a dozen other forum threads. I've tried it on two different websites, and finally, I have created a dozen similar plugs without issues.

The full error in the console is:

```
POST https://foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.4.2:2
```

How do I find the problem? Here's the scoop:

Payload:

```
action: save_book_form
form_nonce: eaf66eb555
sampledata: foobar
```

and

```
action=save_book_form&form_nonce=eaf66eb555&sampledata=foobar
```

Response:

```
0
```

The browser also returns `0`:
`https://foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=save_book_form`

In the main module:

```
function register_manage_library_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 
        'Library',                  // page title
        'Library',                  // menu title
    blah, blah
    }

    require_once ( 'apps/manage-library-functions.php' );
    require_once ( 'apps/save-books.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_manage_library_menu' );
```

In the principal module contains form HTML and sends the form to save on submit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#add_book').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        var data = {
            action:             'save_book_form',
            sampledata:         "foobar"
//blah, blah
        };
        
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

In the callback module:

```
function save_book_form() {

    echo "this was a success";
    wp_die();
        
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_book_form', 'save_book_form' );
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_book_form', 'save_book_form' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `apps/save-books.php` file contains the `save_book_form()` function and the `wp_ajax_save_book_form` hook, the problem is that you're only including this file inside the `admin_menu` hook.

The `admin-ajax.php` file does not run the `admin_menu` hook, so your `apps/save-books.php` file won't be loaded for admin AJAX requests, which means that your action is never hooked.

You need to require those files outside of the `admin_menu` hook.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked instantly and makes perfect sense—a good lesson. I was deceived by previous plugin development—just another reason to not copy and paste code thinking it will work.